# Relationship BelongToMany with additional data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationship, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I've 3 tables:

1. Courses (have category_id)
2. Authors
3. Categories (of courses)

In my Authors model I've added:

```
    public function courses () {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course', 'courses2authors')->where('status','=', 1);
}
```

"courses2authors" is the pivot table.
Then in my controller I retrieve courses info with:

```
$authors = Author::where('status', '=', 1)->orderBy('pos')->with('courses')->get();
```

It's ok but I've only the category_id in ->courses, how to add category name in the model relationship.

I try something like:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course', 'courses2authors')
->where('status','=', 1)->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=',
'courses.category_id')->select('categories.name as categoria');
```

But in this way in take only the category name and not the course data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define `belongsTo` relationship in **Course** Model with **Categories**.

Course Model

```
public function categories () {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories', 'category_id');
}
```

While retrieving `Author` with `Courses` then you can use like this. (Controller code)

```
$authors = Author::where('status', '=', 1)->orderBy('pos')
    ->with('courses',function($query){
         $query->with('categories);
})->get();
```

if you don't want to use like this then you can set $with attribute in `Courses` Model.

```
protected $with = ['categories']; // default with define here.
```

Use in controller :-

```
$authors = Author::where('status', '=', 1)->orderBy('pos')
        ->with('courses')->get();
```

Comment: I set your answer as best one but you can elaborate further how to use protected $with = ['categories']; //thanks.

Comment: Whenever you fetch Courses model object then it will attach default with "categories" , so no need to specify with too

Comment: Thanks, great help!